# Jquery Ajax to PHP script not reading data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, ajax

I have the following `$ajax` code which is meant to send an array with `'title'` and  `'name'` keys populated with data to `script.php`.
This script creates a new instance of a 2D array, and adds it to an existing multidimensional array with the 'name' as the key.

However the `script.php` is not reading the `$newTitle` & `$newName` being sent from the ajax.

I'm sure it's something easy - I am very new to PHP and jQuery.

`javascript:`

```
$.ajax({
    data: {title: 'this', name:'testthis'},
    url: 'script.php',
    method: 'POST',
    success: function(msg) {
        alert(msg);
    }
});
```

`script.php:`

```
//load the existing array into memory
$newLogins =json_decode(unserialize(file_get_contents("config.data")),true);
// get the data from ajax
$newTitle = $_POST["title"];
$newName = $_POST["name"];
//create a new instance of the example array
$addNew = array(
     'password' => 'pw',
     'title' => $newTitle,
     'emails' => array('mymailx@xx.com'));
//add the new array to the existing array with 'name' as key
$newLogins[$newName] =$addNew;
//save it
file_put_contents("config.data", serialize(json_encode($newLogins)));
//send it back to ajax
echo json_encode($newLogins);
```

**EDIT**

Added HTML file below:

```
<?php
$thisLogins = json_decode(unserialize(file_get_contents("config.data")),true);
?>
<head>
<script src="../libs/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../libs/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>
<table id="tableId" border=1>
<thead>
    <tr>
    <th> Project Login</th>
    <th> Project Name</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
<tbody>
<?php foreach( $thisLogins as $name => $infos ): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?= $name ?></td>
        <td><?= $infos["title"]?></td>
        <td><button>Delete</button></td>
    </tr>

<?php endforeach; ?>
</tbody>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript"> 

$.ajax({
    data: {title: 'this', name:'testthis'},
    url: 'script.php',
    method: 'POST',
    success: function(msg) {
        alert(msg);
    }
});
</script>
```

What I'm getting is for output:

```
"":{"password":"caps","title":null,"emails":["helmeri@bsci.com"]}}
```

Comment: This appears to be working just dandy. I'm getting this output: `{"testthis":{"password":"pw","title":"this","emails":["mymailx@xx.com"]}}`. Does your JS console provide any clues?

Comment: Assuming that it's just a few lines, show us the HTML. Are you sure you've got JQuery on the page-- see HPierce's comment.

Comment: I added the HTML files. There is no JS console warnings etc on Firefox. Added my output as well

Answer (score 2):

In order to read data from JSON output, its best if you set content header to JSON in script.php. it will make output perfect for $.ajax function to be easily readable, for example...
`header('Content-Type:application/json;');`

Also remove unnecessary comma in $.ajax function in JavaScript, just for caution need to run the JavaScript code after after the link of jquery.

You can use conditioning in PHP for checking whether there is an empty input or not from JavaScript. For Example...

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST["title"]) && !empty($_POST["name"])){
$newTitle = $_POST["title"];
$newName = $_POST["name"];
/****** process your code here ******/
//create a new instance of the example array
 $addNew = array(
  'password' => 'pw',
  'title' => $newTitle,
  'emails' => array('mymailx@xx.com'));
  //add the new array to the existing array with 'name' as key
  $newLogins[$newName] =$addNew;
 //save it
 file_put_contents("config.data", serialize(json_encode($newLogins)));
 //send it back to ajax
 $output['status'] = 'true';
 $output['error'] = 'none';
 $output['newLogins'] = $newLogins;
 }
else{
$output['status'] = 'false';
$output['error'] = 'Invalid Input';
}

//Setting up proper output
header('Content-Type:application/json;');
echo json_encode($output);
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for this. How would I get the ajax to read if the status was true or false?

Comment: Use this...
$.post('script_url',
        {
           //Your variables here
          {title: 'this', name:'testthis'}
        },
        function(data,status){
 if(data['status']=='true'){
  //it's done
 }
 else
 {
   /* it's not done */ 
 }
        });